# Why is Calculated field in excel not using the formula ,instead summing up

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I created a calculated field using pivot table in excel, but instead of using the formula I provided, it’s summing up.How can I make it use the formula I provided?

Comment: You need to change the type of the calculated field from "sum" to "custom calculation"

Comment: By default, Calculated Fields always apply a SUM aggregation to the values in the columns referenced prior to applying the aggregation you specify. You might need to use a measure within Power Pivot to achieve what you want, though that would depend upon precisely what it is you are wanting to do.

Comment: The problem is that the calculated field doesn’t use the formula I input,  or let me say it calculates wrongly despite me giving the right formula. And I tried figuring out the calculation it does, and  It’s not like it sums ,multiply or divide the fields I input, just can’t figure out what it does to return the wrong answers it returns. @JosWoolley

Comment: Why don't you create a reduced dataset (10 rows' worth or so), which you can then share here along with the results of your Calculated Field formula, together with the results you would expect to see.

Comment: I figured that it doesn’t sum, divide, multiply or average the fields, and it also doesn’t use the formula I provided , and can’t figure out what calculation it does with the fields to return the wrong answers it does. If the suggestion you made can help on the issue , then how do I change it, please? @Horaciux

Comment: Go to the PivotTable Fields pane, and select the field that you want to use for the calculated field.
Drag it to the "Values" area of the PivotTable.
Right-click on the field in the "Values" area and select "Field Settings."
Select "Custom calculation" from the "Summarize value field by" dropdown.
Enter your formula in the "Formula" field.

Comment: It is not giving me the "Custom calculation" option, the only option its giving is the  "choose the type of calculation you want to use to summarize data from the selected field" options, which are the sum, product, average,.... @Horaciux

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra column in your basic data with just 1 in all the cells. Name the column "sum1" or something. In the calculated field you use your formula but divide by the field "sum1".
Tell me if it has worked.
Best regards
Pieter (Belgian_fella)